# scala help need to understand AssociationRules creation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

A newbie qustion. I try to learn Scala from examples , I found some Spark code that creates AssociationRules [source code here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/fpm/AssociationRules.scala)

```
def run[Item: ClassTag](freqItemsets: RDD[FreqItemset[Item]]): RDD[Rule[Item]] = {
// For candidate rule X => Y, generate (X, (Y, freq(X union Y)))
val candidates = freqItemsets.flatMap { itemset =>
  val items = itemset.items
  items.flatMap { item =>
    items.partition(_ == item) match {
      case (consequent, antecedent) if !antecedent.isEmpty =>
        Some((antecedent.toSeq, (consequent.toSeq, itemset.freq)))
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

I try to undersatnd how the `run` function works and how the algorithm understands in`case` that `antecedent` is X and `consequent` is Y. How are the items divided?

Another question: how does the `join` function work (below)? is `freqAntecedent` is `x.freq` ? How does `freqUnion` apprear in `map`?

```
candidates.join(freqItemsets.map(x => (x.items.toSeq, x.freq)))
  .map { case (antecendent, ((consequent, freqUnion), freqAntecedent)) =>
  new Rule(antecendent.toArray, consequent.toArray, freqUnion, freqAntecedent)
}.filter(_.confidence >= minConfidence)
```

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

generate `(X, (Y, freq(X union Y)))` means that the items are pairs (2-Tuple) of values. A Tuple has an `unapply` method that allows pattern matching on it, i.e exactly what you see in the `case` statement. Any time a class implements `unapply`, you can use it in a `case` statement where you can break it up into its attributes and assign each attribute to a variable.

Comment: Thanks ! A line above `x.items.toSeq` contains rule `items` and `x.freq` contains rule frequency , how these two modified to four ? how items were divided to `antecendent` and `consequent` ?

Comment: First, we transform `map(x => (x.items.toSeq, x.freq))`. Now our data type is Tuple2, where the first element is a sequence of items and the second is `x.freq`. Since our data type is now a Tuple2, we can pattern-match on it: `antecendent` (an arbitrary name) and `x.freq`, which is probably itself a Tuple2, so it can be further decomposed into `((consequent, freqUnion), freqAntecedent)`. If all these data types are tuples, they get broken down into components one after the other. I suggest you try to figure out the data types of each expression - it will help make sense of what is going on.